# How does NodeJS handle multi-core concurrency?

Tags: node.js, concurrency

Currently I am working on a database that is updated by another java application, but need a NodeJS application to provide Restful API for website use. To maximize the performance of NodeJS application, it is clustered and running in a multi-core processor.

However, from my understanding, a clustered NodeJS application has a their own event loop on each CPU core, if so, does that mean, with cluster architect, NodeJS will have to face traditional concurrency issues like in other multi-threading architect, for example, writing to same object which is not writing protected? Or even worse, since it is multi-process running at same time, not threads within a process blocked by another...

I have been searching Internet, but seems nobody cares that at all. Can anyone explain the cluster architect of NodeJS? Thanks very much

Add on:
Just to clarify, I am using express, it is not like running multiple instances on different ports, it is actually listening on the same port, but has one process on each CPUs competing to handle requests...

the typical problem I am wondering now is: a request to update Object A base on given Object B(not finish), another request to update Object A again with given Object C (finish before first request)...then the result would base on Object B rather than C, because first request actually finishes after the second one.
This will not be problem in real single-threaded application, because second one will always be executed after first request...

Comment: AFAIK, it doesn't. Node is single threaded. You can run multiple instances of the app in separate processes, but in order for that to work, the app must be stateless. That normally means storing all data that could affect anything other than the current request in an external data store. [Redis](http://redis.io/) provides several useful data structures for this setup, for objects where a traditional database would be overkill.

Comment: Take a look at https://nodejs.org/api/cluster.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The core of your question is:

> NodeJS will have to face traditional concurrency issues like in other multi-threading architect, for example, writing to same object which is not writing protected?

The answer is that that scenario is usually not possible because node.js processes don't share memory. ObjectA, ObjectB and ObjectC in process A are different from ObjectA, ObjectB and ObjectC in process B. And since each process are single-threaded contention cannot happen. This is the main reason you find that there are no semaphore or mutex modules shipped with node.js. Also, there are no threading modules shipped with node.js

This also explains why "nobody cares". Because they assume it can't happen.

The problem with node.js clusters is one of caching. Because ObjectA in process A and ObjectA in process B are completely different objects, they will have completely different data. The traditional solution to this is of course not to store dynamic state in your application but to store them in the database instead (or memcache). It's also possible to implement your own cache/data synchronization scheme in your code if you want. That's how database clusters work after all.

Of course node, being a program written in C, can be easily extended in C and there are modules on npm that implement threads, mutex and shared memory. If you deliberately choose to go against node.js/javascript design philosophy then it is your responsibility to ensure nothing goes wrong.

---

### Additional answer:

> a request to update Object A base on given Object B(not finish), another request to update Object A again with given Object C (finish before first request)...then the result would base on Object B rather than C, because first request actually finishes after the second one.
>   This will not be problem in real single-threaded application, because second one will always be executed after first request...

First of all, let me clear up a misconception you're having. That this is not a problem for a `real single-threaded application`. Here's a single-threaded application in pseudocode:

```
function main () {
    timeout = FOREVER
    readFd = []
    writeFd = []

    databaseSock1 = socket(DATABASE_IP,DATABASE_PORT)
    send(databaseSock1,UPDATE_OBJECT_B)

    databaseSock2 = socket(DATABASE_IP,DATABASE_PORT)
    send(databaseSock2,UPDATE_OPJECT_C)

    push(readFd,databaseSock1)
    push(readFd,databaseSock2)

    while(1) {
        event = select(readFD,writeFD,timeout)
        if (event) {
            for (i=0; i<length(readFD); i++) {
                if (readable(readFD[i]) {
                    data = read(readFD[i])

                    if (data == OBJECT_B_UPDATED) {
                        update(objectA,objectB)
                    }
                    if (data == OBJECT_C_UPDATED) {
                        update(objectA,objectC)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, there's no threads in the program above, just asynchronous I/O using the `select` system call. The program above can easily be translated directly into single-threaded C or Java etc. (indeed, something similar to it is at the core of the javascript event loop).

However, if the response to UPDATE_OBJECT_C arrives before the response to UPDATE_OBJECT_B the final state would be that objectA is updated based on the value of objectB instead of objectC.

No asynchronous single-threaded program is immune to this in any language and node.js is no exception.

Note however that you don't end up in a corrupted state (though you do end up in an unexpected state). Multithreaded programs are worse off because without locks/semaphores/mutexes the call to `update(objectA,objectB)` can be interrupted by the call to `update(objectA,objectC)` and objectA will be corrupted. This is what you don't have to worry about in single-threaded apps and you won't have to worry about it in node.js.

If you need strict temporally sequential updates you still need to either wait for the first update to finish, flag the first update as invalid or generate error for the second update. Typically for web apps (like stackoverflow) an error would be returned (for example if you try to submit a comment while someone else have already updated the comments).

Comment: thanks very much, it helps a a lot, but, just for curiosity, is there a way to prevent reaching the unexpected state? is that a work inside database?